# Error when parse date in FreeMarker

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I got error when formart vietnam time. Language setting with US run fine, but change to VN so got error.

```
Error: on line 20, column 11 in 10157#10197#22325
    The string doesn't match the expected date/time format. The string to parse was: "CN, 15 thg 7 2018 18:54:00 +0700". The expected format was: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz".
```

I using liferay 6.2, display web content use Freemarker template. Here my code.

```
<#assign articleDisplayDate = .vars['reserved-article-display-date'].data />
<#assign AssetEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService" )>
<#assign JournalArticleLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService")>

<#assign currentArticle = JournalArticleLocalService.getArticle(getterUtil.getLong(groupId),.vars['reserved-article-id'].data)>
<#assign currentArticleResourcePrimKey = currentArticle.getResourcePrimKey()>

<#assign currentArticleAssetEntry = AssetEntryLocalService.getEntry("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle", currentArticleResourcePrimKey)/>



<div class="wrapcap">
  <h3 class="title">
     <a href="">${.vars['reserved-article-title'].data}</a>
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="datecomm">
  <span>
  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  <span>${articleDisplayDate?date("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")?string("MMMM, dd yyyy")}</span>
  </span>
  <span><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Số lượt xem: <span>${currentArticleAssetEntry.viewCount}</span></span>
</div>
<div class="desccomm">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="contentcomm">
  ${content.getData()}
</div>
```

Have no idea with this date format.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the name of day and month. What language does that date use (why does it use latin letters)? Try `${.now?string("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")}` to see how the expected format looks.

Comment: Date use Vietnamese. Test result i posted below.

Answer (score 1):

It is reporting the error correctly.

Let's verify together:

> The string doesn't match the expected date/time format. The string to
>   parse was: "CN, 15 thg 7 2018 18:54:00 +0700". The expected format
>   was: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz".

"CN, 15 thg 7 2018 18:54:00 +0700"

so EEE is CN, check.

dd is 15, check.

thg is MMM.  Don't know about that, but check.

yyyy is 7.  Doesn't seem right to me.

hh is 2018.  Definitely not right.

etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I thougt reporting correctly too. But just got error when use Vietnamese, working fine with English though. Have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

https://gsmblog.net/date-objects-liferay-freemarker-web-content-templates/

Seem like this bug is by handled very poorly by liferay.

I solved it with code here:

```
<#-- Retrieve the published date meta data field of the web content -->
<#assign articleDisplayDate = .vars['reserved-article-display-date'].data />

<#-- Save the original page locale for later -->
<#assign originalLocale = locale>

<#-- Set the page locale to the portals default locale -->
<#setting locale = 'en_US'>

<#-- Parse the date to a date object use locale en-US -->
<#assign date = articleDisplayDate?date("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")>

<#-- Create date time formart use originalLocale (Your site localle)  -->
<#assign dateTimeFormat = languageUtil.get(originalLocale, "MMMM, dd yyyy")>

<#-- Result  -->
<#assign date = date?string(dateTimeFormat)>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is test result.

**English:**

- ${articleDisplayDate}:Sun, 15 Jul 2018 18:54:00 +0700
- ${.now?string("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")}: Mon, 20 Aug 2018 10:46:48 GMT+07:00

**Vietnamese:**

- ${articleDisplayDate}: CN, 15 thg 7 2018 18:54:00 +0700
- ${.now?string("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")}: Mon, 20 Aug 2018 10:47:46 GMT+07:00

Comment: This should be part of your question (you can edit it), not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample you have provided the problem seems to be that your `locale` FreeMarker configuration setting is some sort of English (try `${.locale}` to see). When parsing a date/time/datetime, or even numbers, the current locale matters, because the name of days and months, etc. depends on the locale.

So, you should set the `locale` to Vietnamese. Normally, the `locale` FreeMarker configuration setting is set outside the template. If the locale can be different for individual template processings, which all use the same common `Configuration` object, then it can be set on the `freemarker.core.Environment` object for each independently. If for some reason you must set the locale inside the template, that's possible too:

```
<#setting locale="vi_VN">
${"CN, 15 thg 7 2018 18:54:00 +0700"?datetime("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz")}
```

Also note that I'm using `?datetime`, not `?date`. The last means date *only*, which can lead to some glitches elsewhere, since you also have time there.